# RAD Studio 2011 ( ? )

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe

Is there any information available for the next version ( 2011 ) of Delphi / cbuilder from Embarcadero?

Is there a link somewhere pointing to information related to the next Delphi / cbuilder, about when and what might be in it?

Comment: look here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/What's_New

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is outdated, and has no future value. (Specific question about specific third-party IDE that is now 8 versions old.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best official word you will get is the [road map](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39934), which was just published Sept 11th, 2009, by Michael Rozlog.  There may be a new Road Map published soon, but until then, that is the best official word.

From what I understand (most of which is in that road map, or was from the [Delphi Live! Labs](http://www.delphi.org/2009/05/what-is-cooking-in-the-delphi-labs-1/) sessions which you can catch the videos of on [my site](http://www.Dephi.org/),) Delphi Project X (which I am *assuming* is going to be the next version, but it may not) is going to focus on cross platform compilation.

Version after that is I believe going to be Commodore, which is the 64 bit version.

There is also some functional programming and multi-threaded features that are going to be mixed in there someplace.

That road map, even though it is from September, is prior to the Weaver / 2010 release of Delphi, so I am expecting a new road map soon.  That one should have a more clear view of what to be expected.  Keep in mind that these are their goals, and they are subject to change as they go along.  The further our the goal is, the more likely it is to change as things move forward.

As far as releases, they seem to like [releasing in the fall](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Release_Dates).  So in the September, October, November time frame next year.  Of course that is all purely conjecture.  Yadda, yadda, yadda.  So don't make any plans on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jim. I realy wish that there will be a more clear "path" in the near future.

Comment: The pattern is there will be a road map with vague directions, and that is all we will see, except maybe at a conference, until shortly before (maybe a month before) the release, then they will start reveling a lot of details and features.  That is pretty typical.  Even Microsoft will make last minute changes up until the point of release.

Answer (score 3):

This contains all the very long term plans:
["The Future of Delphi Looks Brighter Than Ever Before"](http://www.devia.be/news/article/the-future-of-delphi-looks-brighter-than-ever-before/)

And this is a great Wings of Wind blog post commenting on that:
[Newsflash: The Roadmap.](http://windwings.wordpress.com/2009/09/12/newsflash-the-roadmap/)

Comment: Thanks , it seems that only "general" info is at this time avelable nothing specific.

Answer (score 1):

Now this would be your last option.Give it a look.

[RAD Studio 2010, Delphi, C++Builder and Delphi Prism in the News](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39874)

Comment: Realy thank you guys , but again nothing there. It seems that there is "thick fog" regarding to what is the next version of RAD Studio !!!! Can any one explain that ? ( at least try !!).

Comment: What do you exactly want?I am afraid I can't explain it.But surely I can give you the source only.

Comment: This link provides lot of info on the upcoming version.

Answer (score 1):

See some screenshots of D2011 at http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=54149&sid=2bf2c803da215eb29a4135e8c4dd829f

Answer (score 1):

New info:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40766

Answer (score 0):

[DELPHI HATER'S BLOG](http://delphihaters.blogspot.com/2009/06/delphi-64-bits-in-2010-or-maybe-2011-or.html)

[Delphi and C++Builder Roadmap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/36620)

Comment: Thanks for the link , but there is only "general" information. Sebastian.

Comment: You're not going to find anything more detailed than that roadmap link from official sources.

Answer (score 0):

Some new information can be found here:

[Delphi 2011 and beyond: The Libraries Ahead](http://wings-of-wind.com/2010/03/14/delphi-2011-and-beyond-the-libraries-ahead/)

> We know that VCL is tied to Win32 API,
>   hence there was a lot of speculation
>   about a presumable VCL 2.0 which will
>   be the cross-platform cousin of the
>   actual VCL. Such a library exists (is
>   in development) and will be delivered
>   alongside with VCL which will be kept
>   for Windows development. The team
>   called it VCLX in the newsgroups and
>   elsewhere – even if it seems that the
>   actual, release name will be different
>   ;-) – and in the roadmap it is written
>   about it “Limited backward
>   compatibility”.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading a post on the official Embarcadero forums by Alen Bauer himself, saying that if they published any details about Delphi 2011, the sales of Delphi2010 would drop and Embarcadero would soon go bankrupt.

Now go figure...

Answer (score 0):

The version after Delphi 2010 has been released it is now called Delphi XE.

Details of what was actually released can be found on [Embarcadero's Website](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi).